# Multiple CSV files input for hugging face table question-answering in Python

Tags: huggingface

I am trying to write a code in HuggingFace Python to input multiple CSV files and feed them to the tokenizer for table question-answering. If I were to input only one CSV file, the code would look like this:

```
from transformers import pipeline
import pandas as pd

prepare table + question
data = {"Actors": ["Brad Pitt", "Leonardo Di Caprio", "George Clooney"], "Number of movies": ["87", "53", "69"]}
table = pd.read_csv("csv_file_1.csv")
question = "how many movies does Leonardo Di Caprio have?"
```

pipeline model
Note: you must to install torch-scatter first.

```
tqa = pipeline(task="table-question-answering", model="google/tapas-large-finetuned-wtq")
```

result

```
print(tqa(table=table, query=query)['cells'][0]) #53
```

If there were more than just one csv file, how would we define table?

I tried loading multiple csv files through load_dataset and store it in variable dataset, then tried: `table = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dataset)` OR `table = dataset`

but none of these approached worked